# How to build MLIR for TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, compiler-optimization, multi-level

Is there a guide/examples on building TensorFlow with MLIR?

I'm trying to learn how TensorFlow and XLA dialects are used in the TensorFlow ecosystem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guide yet unfortunately. If you use the Tflite converter then you are using TensorFlow and MLIR and you can see in the pipeline construction how it is used, the guides around that though are focused on the user rather than the developer. For XLA we are actively working on rolling out the new TF XLA bridge that uses MLIR, but it is not ready for general external use yet. And same is true for the new XLA HLO emitters using MLIR. I'm not sure for TFRT, but I'd assume there it would similarly be focussed on the user rather than developer.

This was an item on a recent documentation sprint, but unfortunately that task wasn't completed and we have to address that still. The document will be on tensorflow.org/mlir eventually. I'll try and remember to ping here once completed.

Comment: Thanks for the update, looking forward for the documentation :)